# Using Google Analytics to establish busiest time of day

Tags: google-analytics, users, analytics

I am trying to find a way to establish my sites busiest hour, but when using the "hour of the day" metric, each seems to have a date specific code, rather than just a number from 0-23, as I would expect.

Any ideas how to obtain this info, or if I should be using a different service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. When viewing your website data, choose Visitors > Visitor Trending > Visits from the Analytics left-hand sidebar menu:

   [image: Visits in Google Analytics]
2. Select the date range you're interested in, and then click the clock to the right of "Graph by" in the top right of your screen:

   [image: graph by time google analytics]

You'll see a graph and bar chart showing visits by time for the date range you selected:

[image: most popular time google analytics]

It's important to note that the times in the left column are in whatever timezone you set up for the site when you first created it in Analytics. Check the timezone in the [site profile](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55512) here:

1. Click the "Analytics Settings" link in the top left of your screen:

   [image: analytics settings]
2. Click the 'Edit' link to the right of the site you're interested in:

   [image: edit link]
3. The timezone for that website appears under "Main Website Profile Information". Click the "Edit" link to change it:

   [image]

Comment: +1 For taking the trouble to add screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

The graph by hour option seems <del>to be gone</del> to be back again. You can also create a custom report that looks something like the "rush hour" reports in AWStats. [Google Analytics Day of Week and Hour of Day Reports](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2012/07/analytics-day-of-week-hour-of-day-report.html) discusses the report in detail. Short summary:

1. Create a new custom report
2. In the first tab, choose "Flat Report" layout
3. Add the dimension "Hour" and metric "Visits"
4. Add additional metrics (optional)
5. Save and preview

Comment: Thank you TrueBlue. Be Sure to check the attached link above. The information has changed again.